# Debugging an .aspx file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm showing my Default.aspx in VS2017' internal web browser using the button "Show in Browser (Internal Browser)".

It works. I see the page, and I see the textbox and button that I've defined.

Now I've set breakpoints in Default.aspx like this:

[image]

Web.config is configured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What might be the reason why the breakpoints aren't hit?

Comment: That looks like JavaScript, you can do normal debugging in JavaScript, that only works in code behind/c# code for debugging

Comment: thats javascript not c#, you need to use your browser debugger

Comment: If you put debugger; keyword in your code where you want to debug and if you use Internet Explorer, you can debug your aspx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Internet explorer,

if you put debugger; keyword in your javascript code, you can debug your javascript code.

If you use Google Chrome, you can put the same keyword. This time you should open the developper tools of the google chrome by pressing on F12 key on your keyboard. If the developper tools is open, you can debug your javascript code in Google Chrome developper tools.

```
 function alertSomething(){
  debugger; //In internet explorer debugger will be hit directly (if you put a breakpoint). In google chrome, debugger will be hit if the developper tools is open.
  alert('test');

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to debug it in VS?

Comment: You can't debug javascript code like c#. Did you try the same thing in visual studio browser ?

Comment: Yes, I did. :-)

Comment: Happy for you :)